# How to setup serivce-worker.js properly using webpack in Laravel + ReactJS project? PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

The project I built is in ReactJS (frontend) with Laravel 5.8.27 (backend as REST API). I'm trying to setup PWA (Progressive Web App) for this project so I don't need to use mobile browser directly.

I prepared manifest.json and all the icons using generator from https://app-manifest.firebaseapp.com/:

```
{
    "name": "TRT",
    "short_name": "TRT",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "/",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "splash_pages": null
}
```

Then I needed to setup service-worker.js file in my "public" folder of my project. I used https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/workbox
I installed it and included this module in webpack.mix.js file which is in root folder of this project. I've just put a line to require 'laravel-mix-workbox' and in 'mix' object I added additional method '.generateSW()'. It looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
require('laravel-mix-react-css-modules');
require('laravel-mix-workbox');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .reactCSSModules()
   .generateSW();
```

Then I put the link to manifest.json file
`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`
and JS script in main index file:

```
<script>
            // Check that service workers are supported
            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
                window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
                });
            }
        </script>
```

to register the serive-worker.js which was created when I run 
`npm run dev`

So, after that I went to my browser to check if it's ok. There is manifest.json file when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest.json and there is also service-worker.js file in public folder of my project which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Welcome to your Workbox-powered service worker!
 *
 * You'll need to register this file in your web app and you should
 * disable HTTP caching for this file too.
 *
 * The rest of the code is auto-generated. Please don't update this file
 * directly; instead, make changes to your Workbox build configuration
 * and re-run your build process.
 */

importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.5e21538faef9d96ee3cc4d11ed2229cf.js"
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

So, when I went to the Google Dev Tools (Application tab) to see if everything is ok, it turned out that there's manifest.json file but there's problem with service-worker. The message is 
`"No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest."`
So I started to test scenarios of "start_url" and "scope" in manifest.json but I left it with "/" because it's my root folder.

I started to search stack and Google for solution. I found that there should be SSL set up for this project (Is it really needed in development environment?) so I used Laravel's Homestead to setup a project with SSL. No I have: https://project.test working. Then it turned out that in Google Dev Tools (Application tab) there is still `"No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest."`. 
I went to the Service Worker tab there and it shows service-worker.js file but with a problem. I went to console to see this: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` in service-worker.js:1

Now I have no idea what causes the problem. When it comes to the fact that I shouldn't change the service-worker.js file which is autogenerated, what can I do to solve the problem. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. There was problem with webpack configuration. I've just added to webpack.mix.js

```
const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [new GenerateSW()],
    output: {
        publicPath: ''
    }
});
```

That solved the problem.